# jQuery Accordion Expand List of Daily Events

Tags: jquery, wrapall

I'm trying to get the jQuery accordion to expand/collapse a list of daily events.

The entire event list is inside `<div id="accordion"><!-- events here --></div>`

Each day has an `<h3>` header included inside the accordion div with the date `<h3>Tuesday, October 20, 2015</h3>`, for example. Each individual event is in a list below the date header. The list uses classes to group the events by day, so October 20th events would all have `<li class="Oct202015event">`.

I think, in order to get the accordion to work correctly, I need to wrap each day's list of events in a , which will then get the appropriate expand/collapse classes.

What I have so far is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true
  });
  // Collect all li classes ending in "event"
  var $list = $("li[class$='event']");

  // Collect all unique class names
  var classNames = $list.map(function() {
      return this.className;
  });
  classNames = $.unique(classNames.get());
// wrap all of the same class names with a <ul>
  $.each(classNames, function(i, className) {
        $list.filter(function() {
            return $(this).hasClass(className);
        }).wrapAll("<ul>");
  });
});
```

I'm having a few problems with this.

1. All lists should be collapsed when the page loads, and currently they are all expanded.
2. The code I'm using isn't wrapping around the `<li>` correctly.

[Here is the page I'm using this on](http://surpriseazmom.com/event-calendar/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your code for wrapping in `<ul>`'s above the code that initializes your accordion.

If you initialize the accordion first, then it will just use the first `<li>` in each list as the content for the corresponding `<h3>`.

Additionally, the `collapsible: true` will allow all headings to be collapsed, but you also need `active: false` to have them all collapsed upon init, as mentioned by @DaOgre.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Collect all li classes ending in "event"
  var $list = $("li[class$='event']");

  // Collect all unique class names
  var classNames = $list.map(function() {
      return this.className;
  });
  classNames = $.unique(classNames.get());
// wrap all of the same class names with a <ul>
  $.each(classNames, function(i, className) {
        $list.filter(function() {
            return $(this).hasClass(className);
        }).wrapAll("<ul>");
  });
  
  $('#accordion').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
  });  
  
});
```

```css
h3.event-date {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">

  <h3 class="event-date">Tuesday, October 20, 2015</h3>
  <li class="Oct202015event"><a href='http://www.tolmachoff-farms.com/corn_maze_pumpkin_patch_glendale_arizona.html'><strong>Tomalchoff Farm Corn Maze and Pumpkin Patch</strong></a>: 5726 N 75th Ave Glendale, AZ
    <br />Time: 11am-8pm
    <br />Cost: $9 ages 2 and up
    <br />Available Activities: Inflatable bouncers, Kids Zone, Petting Zoo , Train rides ($2.00 extra) on weekends only
  </li>
  <li class="Oct202015event"><a href='http://www.tolmachoff-farms.com/corn_maze_pumpkin_patch_glendale_arizona.html'><strong>Tomalchoff Farm Corn Maze and Pumpkin Patch</strong></a>: 5726 N 75th Ave Glendale, AZ
    <br />Time: 11am-8pm
    <br />Cost: $9 ages 2 and up
    <br />Available Activities: Inflatable bouncers, Kids Zone, Petting Zoo , Train rides ($2.00 extra) on weekends only
  </li>
  <li class="Oct202015event"><a href='http://www.mothernaturesfarm.com/pumpkinpatch.aspx'><strong>Halloween Pumpkin Patch at Mother Nature&#8217;s Farm</strong></a>: 1663 E Baseline Rd Gilbert, AZ
    <br />Time: 9am-9pm
    <br />Cost: $10 per child
    <br />Available Activities: Food Vendors, Petting Zoo , admission includes a pumpkin
  </li>
  <li class="Oct202015event"><a href='http://vertucciofarms.com/events/'><strong>Vertuccio Farms Corn Maze and Fall Festival</strong></a>: 4011 S Power Rd Mesa, AZ
    <br />Time: 9am-9pm
    <br />Cost: $9 per person
  </li>
  <li class="Oct202015event"><a href='http://www.schnepffarms.com/event/pumpkin-chili-party/'><strong>Schnepf Farms Pumpkin and Chili Party</strong></a>: 24810 S Rittenhouse Road Queen Creek, AZ
    <br />Time: 8am-4pm
    <br />Cost: $17 per person
  </li>

  <h3 class="event-date">Wednesday, October 21, 2015</h3>
  <li class="Oct212015event"><a href='http://www.azstatefair.com'><strong>Arizona State Fair</strong></a>: See oct 16th Phoenix, AZ
    <br />Time: Noon-9pm
    <br />Cost: see oct 16th
  </li>
  <li class="Oct212015event"><a href='http://www.tolmachoff-farms.com/corn_maze_pumpkin_patch_glendale_arizona.html'><strong>Tomalchoff Farm Corn Maze and Pumpkin Patch</strong></a>: 5726 N 75th Ave Glendale, AZ
    <br />Time: 11am-8pm
    <br />Cost: $9 ages 2 and up
    <br />Available Activities: Inflatable bouncers, Kids Zone, Petting Zoo , Train rides ($2.00 extra) on weekends only
  </li>
  <li class="Oct212015event"><a href='http://www.mothernaturesfarm.com/pumpkinpatch.aspx'><strong>Halloween Pumpkin Patch at Mother Nature&#8217;s Farm</strong></a>: 1663 E Baseline Rd Gilbert, AZ
    <br />Time: 9am-9pm
    <br />Cost: $10 per child
    <br />Available Activities: Food Vendors, Petting Zoo , admission includes a pumpkin
  </li>
  <li class="Oct212015event"><a href='http://vertucciofarms.com/events/'><strong>Vertuccio Farms Corn Maze and Fall Festival</strong></a>: 4011 S Power Rd Mesa, AZ
    <br />Time: 9am-9pm
    <br />Cost: $9 per person
  </li>
  <li class="Oct212015event"><a href='http://www.schnepffarms.com/event/pumpkin-chili-party/'><strong>Schnepf Farms Pumpkin and Chili Party</strong></a>: 24810 S Rittenhouse Road Queen Creek, AZ
    <br />Time: 8am-4pm
    <br />Cost: $17 per person
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. I knew it was close but didn't think the order mattered. Also, I had to add `heightStyle: "content"` after the `active: false,` because each `<ul>` was getting a height set to 7826px despite the content only filling up a small fraction of that space.

Answer (score 0):

In order for everything to be closed you want `active: false` underneath where you set collapsible to true.

Not sure what you mean that the code isnt wrapping around the LI